# How do I convert this AppleScript to osascript?

Tags: applescript, launchd, login-script, osascript

I have written an AppleScript and want to convert it to an osascript so I can run it on launch using launchd. Is there any way I can convert this to osascript or do I have to rewrite the whole script as an osascript? If it can't be done is there at least a way to run it as osascript in the terminal? Thank you!

```
on idle
       tell application "System Events" to ¬
    if exists process "Launchpad" then run script
        tell application "Launchpad"
            delay 0
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "b" using {control down, option down, command down}
            delay 0
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "b" using {control down, option down, command down}
            delay 0
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "b" using {control down, option down, command down}
            delay 0
        end tell
end idle
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to run it once per second or less frequently, you could save it as a normal script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if not (exists process "Launchpad") then return
    repeat 3 times
        keystroke "b" using {control down, option down, command down}
    end repeat
end tell
```

And repeat running the script with launchd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.stackoverflow.11945633</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Library/Scripts/script.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The property list has to be loaded manually with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackoverflow.11945633.plist`. Applying changes requires unloading and loading it.

Programs are sent a SIGKILL signal after 20 seconds by default. You can override the timeout by adding an `ExitTimeOut` key. See `man launchd.plist`.

The script doesn't actually work for changing the Launchpad background. Launchpad.app is just a dummy application that quits immediately when it's opened.

If you just want to change the background style, you can do it with `defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-background-filter -int 2; killall Dock`.